# PHP Shared Data

Tags: php

I'm working on a small project, and I was hit with a brick wall today; one that I surprisingly couldn't find an answer to.

So heres my setup,

```
  config.php => loads 'user.php' and 'project.php'
  user.php => class script loaded into 'config.php'
  project.php => class script loaded into 'config.php'
  main.php => uses 'config.php' to access 'user.php' and 'project.php'
```

Now, to clarify my problem, I want 'user.php' to be able to access 'project.php' through 'config.php'.

**config.php**

```
require_once( 'connect.php' );
require_once( 'user.php' );
require_once( 'project.php' );

// ...
```

**user.php**

```
Project::function(...);

// ...
```

I want 'user.php' to be able to access 'config.php' to access variables and other classes, and I know 'require_once' only let's config inherit from the specified file, but I'm wondering if there's a workaround that lets both access eachother.

Any suggestions? User and Project are in two entirely separate directories for specific reasoning.

Comment: First, I would suggest using namespaces and an autoloader (like Composer).

Comment: Including files is no different than having them all in one file from a base perspective... code in the past cannot see code in the future.  Include `project.php` before `user.php` if you want `user.php` to be able to see it.

Comment: Are these classes just groups of static functions?

Comment: @user574632, for the most part.

Comment: @Mattt, I feel like my brain just shat itself, such a simple solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your config.php, include project.php prior to including user.php. This should give user.php access to everything in project.php.